# XSL Match to first occurrence of values in child node, then extract value from sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, nodes

I have XML data which has a structure like below. I am trying to evaluate the Xid value to see if the stop is multiple values, say location 1 or location 2, but only match to the first hit that it finds in the structure. I then need it to output the Date value for that stop.

```
<ShipmentStop>
    <StopSequence>1</StopSequence>
        <LocationRef>
            <LocationGid>
                <Gid>
                    <Xid>LOCATION 1</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </LocationGid>
        <ArrivalTime>
            <EventTime>
                <EstimatedTime>
                    <Date>20181128070000</Date>
                </EstimatedTime>
            </EventTime>
        </ArrivalTime>
</ShipmentStop>
<ShipmentStop>
    <StopSequence>2</StopSequence>
        <LocationRef>
            <LocationGid>
                <Gid>
                    <Xid>LOCATION 2</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </LocationGid>
        <ArrivalTime>
            <EventTime>
                <EstimatedTime>
                    <Date>20181129070000</Date>
                </EstimatedTime>
            </EventTime>
        </ArrivalTime>
</ShipmentStop>
```

I'm trying to build the below code, but I'm having some issues.

```
<xsl:for-each select="ShipmentStop[/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 1' or /LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 2'][1]">
    <ArrivalTime>
        <xsl:value-of select="ArrivalTime/EventTime/EstimatedTime/Date"/>                               
    </ArrivalTime>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming a well-formed XML below. I have added a root node named `root`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <ShipmentStop>
        <StopSequence>1</StopSequence>
        <LocationRef>
            <LocationGid>
                <Gid>
                    <Xid>LOCATION 1</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </LocationGid>
        </LocationRef>
        <ArrivalTime>
            <EventTime>
                <EstimatedTime>
                    <Date>20181128070000</Date>
                </EstimatedTime>
            </EventTime>
        </ArrivalTime>
    </ShipmentStop>
    <ShipmentStop>
        <StopSequence>2</StopSequence>
        <LocationRef>
            <LocationGid>
                <Gid>
                    <Xid>LOCATION 2</Xid>
                </Gid>
            </LocationGid>
        </LocationRef>
        <ArrivalTime>
            <EventTime>
                <EstimatedTime>
                    <Date>20181129070000</Date>
                </EstimatedTime>
            </EventTime>
        </ArrivalTime>
    </ShipmentStop>    
</root>
```

In your original xpath, you have used

```
ShipmentStop[/LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 1' 
    or /LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 2'][1]
```

Notice the use of `/` in `/LocationRef`. When you do that, you are searching from the root node of your XML, thus it will fail. To use the context node, just add a period before the slash, such as

```
ShipmentStop[./LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 1' 
    or ./LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 2'][1]
```

or you could delete the `./` in the xpath. Such as:

```
ShipmentStop[LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 1' 
    or LocationRef/LocationGid/Gid/Xid='LOCATION 2'][1]
```

since `LocationRef` is a child of `ShipmentStop` node.